# Is it a good idea to add a "passphrase" as part of a PDA seed to store data encrypted on-chain?

Tags: pda, account-data, encryption, data-storage

Thinking about approaches to simplify e2e encryption, this is one of the ideas that came to mind.

The seed then could further be used to encrypt the PDAs data.

Sharing the passphrase between the parties that should have access to the data would make this probably something one would call a symmetric cryptographic approach.

A sub-question to this would be whether the contents of a PDA seed are somehow publicly accessible (intentionally or accidentally, e.g., while browsing Solana Explorer).

I'm super new to cryptographic concepts, therefore some kindness and reasons whilst picking apart and destroying these thoughts would be superb.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it's a good idea to have any function to the passphrase other than to encrypt the data.

The program bytecode is public, and the raw transaction input is public. If that passphrase is ever included in a transaction, that will hint at or simply expose that passphrase, and if the data is also encrypted with the seed from that passphrase it will also decrypt the data.

That's a security self-sabotage you don't want to do when the simplest way to encrypt data end-to-end is to, well, to simply encrypt the data end-to-end.